# Picking entries at specific indices in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have this array:

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

How would I get entries 2 and 4 (say) from the array? I'd love something like

```
x, y = a.entries_at(2, 4)
```

but I want something built-in. Is there anything in the Ruby stdlib that does this? It's hard to google for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're spot on with your guess. It's called [`values_at`](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/Array/values_at):

```
irb(main):001:0> [0,1,2,3,4,5].values_at(2, 4)
=> [2, 4]
```

Comment: woah! fail at google that I got so close but no cigar! thanks @Niklas

Comment: actually, I was looking at [them](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-at)! guess I failed though.

Comment: on the plus side, seems based on the other answers that not everybody knows this. :)

Comment: @Peter: Nevermind my earlier comment, it's really not that obvious :)

Answer (score -1):

There is a method called `fetch` that you could use in the manner that you have indicated:

```
a.fetch(1)
```

would return `1` in the case of your example.